# Jquery Mobile add label to radio buttons controlgroup

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, haml

I have a form, with four radio buttons, and i can't figure out how to add a label to that radio buttons, something like this

LABEL ........ Radio1Radio2Radio3Radio4

The radio buttons code:

```
%div{"data-role" => "fieldcontain"}
  //I think here i need to add something
  %div{"data-role" => "controlgroup", "data-type" => "horizontal"}
    - @models.each do |rep| 
      %label{for: "#{rep.text}_#{c.id}"}= rep.text
      = radio_button_tag "answers[#{c.id}]", id: "#{rep.text}_#{c.id}"
```

I tryied several ways, but the best i can get, is a label like this

LABEL

Radio1Radio2Radio3Radio4

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. What i needed was a %fieldset instead of a %div on the second line

First three rows from the code above, need to look like this

```
%div{"data-role" => "fieldcontain"}
  %fieldset{"data-role" => "controlgroup", "data-type" => "horizontal"}
    %legend= Label
```